# How to restrict tablet screen orientation?

Tags: orientation

I want to restrict my tablet to launch at specific screen orientation like *landscape*. I'm taking here about the whole tablet not a specific app, and for sure I'm not taking about locking off the **Auto Rotate** in the tablet after it launches, I'm taking about restricting the tablet to launch initially at *landscape|protrait*.

Comment: Do you just mean that you want auto rotate turned off when it boots? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DanHulme no, I want to let it open but just want to make the default orientation for the tablet is an orientation i define, So the lockscreen, homepage, ...etc will be at that orientation

Comment: I don't understand. What's the difference between having a "default orientation" and turning off auto rotate?

Comment: @DanHulme when turning on the tablet, It will turn on in specific orientation, in my tablet it's portrait, I want to make it as landscape.

Comment: Surely you could just hold it sideways and it will rotate?

Comment: @RossC you are joking :D right ? :D

Comment: Nope, there's a few problems here:  Every app can override the setting you have (some games ONLY run in portrait for example), and I honestly don't understand why you don't get a launcher and/or Lockscreen that supports rotation and hold the tablet sideways, then everything will be in landscape.... No need to lock, or set anything at all. Some launchers let you set the rotation in degrees also, like Nova Launcher IIRC.

Comment: @RossC I see your point, but this tab will run only one app, and I added the solution I reached as an answer now, and you will notice that I disabled the rotation after managing the rotation i needed, and in my case the status bar won't be there, so won't anyone change the orientation ;)

Comment: Ok, cool, glad you got it sorted out. The issue was not clear (only one app) etc. Maybe just get that app locked in landscape would be a solution also (rather than writing a new app) but the answer may well suit your needs better anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer, **an app** that will run just one time.

create an app and add a permission to it's manifest to **write_settings** & **listen-to-boot** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

then make a `receiver` class which **extends** `BroadcastReceivertype`, with the fowlloing permissions:

```
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" 
        android:name="com.example.BootCompletedReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

then in the `onReceive()` method of the `receiver` class:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        //To handle device rotation 
        Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0);
        Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, Surface.ROTATION_90); // 0 for default, then 90, 180, 270
```

Then run this app just one time to write that permissions to the system, and then you don't need it again.